# How to scale data with a center that doesn't change with scikit-learn and python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, normalization, data-preprocessing

I am attempting to scale a dateset to train a machine learning model on using python and scikit-learn.  I want to scale a dataset but maintain that all the raw values that are negative remain negative post scaling and all the raw values that are positive remain positive after scaling.

Something like this pseudo code for a single feature:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

array = [[-5.0, 0.0, 1.25, 2.5]]
scaler = preprocessing.SomeScaler(feature_range=(-1,1), center=0)
scaler = scaler.fit(array)
print("Scaled:", scaler.transform(array))
#should print Scaled: [[-1.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.5]]

#data arriving after initial scaling might look like this:
scaler = scaler.fit([[-0.1, 0.1, 7.0, 10.0]])
print("Scaled:", scaler.transform(array))
#should print Scaled: [[-0.02, 0.02, 1.4, 2.0]]
```

I am new to machine learning, so I am hoping I just don't know the terms / functions of scikit-learn well enough yet.  Does something like my above `SomeScaler` exist in scikit-learn or perhaps another python library?

Comment: Could you further explain what you're trying to achieve? Why do you need to keep the signs of your feature as is?

Comment: The data is the value of an asset over time.  My thought is that it’s important to keep wether the value of the asset increase or decreased rather than just scaling it such that it’s possible for a given feature that a small increase in value could scale to a negative negative.  I have many features of this type so I thought further some of this discrepancy favoring different positive change to negative scaled or negative change to positive scaled might be problematic.  I also thought scaling -1 to 1 Bette than 0 to 1 for this type of change over time.  -Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Firstly, if you want an array of 1 feature, 4 values you need to reshape your array.

```
import numpy as np
print('This is an array of 1-value for 4-features', np.array([[-5.0, 0.0, 1.25, 2.5]]).shape)
print('This is an array of 4-values for 1-feature', np.array([-5.0, 0.0, 1.25, 2.5]).shape)
#[output] This is an array of 1-value for 4-features (1, 4)
#[output] This is an array of 4-values for 1-feature (4,)
```

2. Secondly, you can scale using [**MaxAbsScaler**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MaxAbsScaler.html):

> ```
> Scale each feature by its maximum absolute value.
> This estimator scales and translates each feature individually such that the maximal absolute value of each feature in the training set will be 1.0. It does not shift/center the data, and thus does not destroy any sparsity.
> ```

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
import numpy as np

array = [-5.0, 0.0, 1.25, 2.5]
#Reshape your data using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array to make it 2D
array = np.array(array).reshape(-1, 1)
print("Array shape after reshaping it to a 2D array: ",array.shape)
scaler = preprocessing.MaxAbsScaler()
scaler = scaler.fit(array)
print("Scaled:", scaler.transform(np.array(array).reshape(-1, 1)))

#[output] Array shape after reshaping it to a 2D array:  (4, 1)
#[output] Scaled: [[-1.  ]
#                  [ 0.  ]
#                  [ 0.25]
#                  [ 0.5 ]]
```

Imputers usually require arrays to be 2D that is why we used reshape to add a 2nd dimension.

Comment: The sample outputs you have here would not meet my expectations. I want floats between -1 and 1, not only 3 discreet values -1,0,1.

Comment: I think I realized I did not clarify, my example was not intended to be 4 features, but 4 values for 1 feature.

Comment: Then I think the way the array is shaped is wrong. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you.  That appears to be the scaler I was looking for.  And thank you for the array shape reminder, I'm still getting a handle on all the python array & matrix type things, most of my code experience is in PHP where any and all arrays, lists, dicts, tuples etc are all just an array.